# note++ file is already open bug?

Tags: html

usually I could save and overwrite my file without any problem but now, a message keeps poping up when I try to/[this thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpwRF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to copy your code, afterwards close all tabs and then open a new tab and paste your code again. Then it should save again had this error a few times this solution fixed it most of the time.

Comment: tried it but still wont work, still gives the same pop up mesage

Comment: And saving to another directory still causes this error?

Comment: yeah it still keeps poping up but saving it as another type and then saving it again as the original type works, but it is very annoying

Comment: Might have to reinstall notepad++ it may be corrupted is it up-to-date?

Comment: the pop up actually started to appear after I updated Note++ and I Have tried to uninstall and install but still does not work

Comment: Then u have to wait for a patch:/